# Unable to convert DateTime from SQL Server to C# DateTime

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I wrote a program in C# that uses dates. It takes the value from a SQL Server table. I was using Windows 7 and the program worked fine. I had this line of code:

```
DateTime fechaOperacion = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["FechaOperacion"]);
```

The reader returned a date in a 24h format and I was able to convert that to a `DateTime` variable.

Now I did a system upgrade to Windows 10 and that same line of code is throwing the following error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. there is an unknown word starting at index 20.

And now the reader returns a.m. / p.m. format, and at index 20 there is a.m or p.m.

I have tried the following things:

- Rephrasing the line of code to:

  1. `Convert.ToDateTime(reader["FechaOperacion"], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`
  2. `reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("FechaOperacion"));`
- Convert the culture to 24h format

  ```
  System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(1033);
  ```

But none of that seems to work, I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Define "it does not seem to work". In particular, what's the result of `reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("FechaOperacion"))`, which is the correct way to read a `DATETIME` column independently of any format?

Comment: What **exactly** is `reader["FechaOperacion"]` returning? the fact that it mentions `String`  means that it isn't "sql DateTime" - a SQL `datetime`  value would be fine and doesn't need to be parsed. So: what is it?

Comment: If `FechaOperacion` is a DATETIME column, then it sounds like it's a display issue.  What happens if you do a `var dateStr = fechaOperacion.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");`?  What is the value of `dateStr`?

Comment: You don't have to convert a SQL `datetime` to a C# DateTime. They are equivalent. If you think you need to convert anything, it's because you are using strings instead of `datetime`. Instead of using `Convert` you shuould be able to use a direct cast, ie `(DateTime)`. If you can't you are returning strings

Comment: From what I read in your question I'm understanding that you are storing your date in nvarchar/varchar in the db which is not a good idea. If you are using datetime, you don't need to convert it.

Comment: A database `datetime` value has no format, it's a binary value just like `DateTime`. What *are* you using in the database?

Answer (score 7):

Ultimately, the underlying problem here is storing a value that represents a date/time  as textual data (meaning, some kind of `[n][var]char({max|n})`, or at a push: `[n]text`). This has multiple problems:

- it takes more space
- it cannot be sorted correctly / efficiently
- it cannot be indexed correctly / efficiently
- it cannot be filtered correctly / efficiently
- it leads to parsing errors  between client and server
- it has all sorts of localization and internationalization problems

What you should have is a `datetime`  / `date` / `time` / etc column. This is then stored as a **number** (not a string) that requires zero parsing and will work reliably without any conversion problems.

---

Note: it *could* be that  you are storing it correctly but formatting it  inside the `select` statement of your query. In which case, just **don't do that**; return the date-time raw, and let the receiving client worry about how to display it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your actual format, you can define a suitable format list and do a conversion like below

```
string[] mfs = { "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",  "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"};

var dat = DateTime.ParseExact("04/23/1945 8:45:22 PM", mfs, 
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
```